# TFS 2015 board customization error - Field identifier does not exist or is invalid

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We have amended our WIT definitions for Bug and User Story to include some new states. In accordance with that, the processConfig has also be updated.

Everything looks OK but when we try to configure the board (using the cog wheel link below the burndown chart)

[image: cog wheel to configure board]

we get the following error when attempted to check the 'Show ID' checkbox on any of the work item types.

[image: error message when attempted to save settings]

The error is as follows:

---

*An error has prevented us from saving your settings. Please review the error messages before continuing. You may need to refresh your page and try again.


**Field identifier 'Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork' does not exist or is invalid for 'Bug' card type.***

---

The ReminaingWork field is not present in our bug definition - and I don't think it should be. It's as if TFS is saying that the *only* way it will allow bugs on the board is to include that field. This isn't right as bugs are already appearing on the board - I just want to include some additional information (i.e. the ID).

I think part of my issue is my understanding of how the WIT definitions and the processConfig relate to one another. The states in both map correctly but there clearly is something that I am missing...

Answer (score -1):

The error is telling you precisely what the problem is. You're trying to treat bugs as tasks; tasks need the Remaining Work field to be factored into capacity planning and burndowns.

Comment: I get that but what causes TFS to infer that I want to treat bugs as tasks? I don't want to do that - I just want to update the board to display another field.